# Why do we have to add a "clr" (clean input wire) while forming a T flip-flop in Verilog with Vivado?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, vivado, flip-flop, digital-design

I am trying to form a T flip-flop in Verilog. I am studying verilog from "Digital System Design with FPGA: Implementation using verilog and vhdl" and the code for T flip-flop is here below:

```
module t_flip_flop(t,clk,clr,q,qn);

input t,clk,clr;
output reg q,qn;

always @(posedge clk or negedge clr)
begin
if(clr==0)
q<=0;qn<=1;
else
q<=q^t;
qn<=~(q^t);
end
```

I understand the xor part that we use this because of the toggle operation. I tried to form it without using "clr", but it didn't work. (I am using "clr" as clear input which is for resetting the flip-flop). Can't I do it without using "clr"?

I tried to change code like this below:

```
module t_flip_flop(t,clk,q,qn);

input t,clk;
output reg q,qn;

always @(posedge clk)
if(t)
begin
q<=q^t;
qn<=~(q^t);
end
```

But in the simulation, I get "x" for both `q` and `qn` in Vivado. I was expecting to get the same results as the code with "clr".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `clr` signal is used to properly initialize `q` and `qn`.

You declared `q` as a `reg` type.  In Verilog simulations, `reg` is initialized to x (the "unknown" value).

Consider your code without `clr`.  At time 0, q=x.  Let's say the posedge of clk is at 10ns and t=1 at that time.  The assignment:

```
q<=q^t;
```

is evaluated like:

```
q <= x ^ 1;
```

Verilog evaluates `x ^ 1` as `x`.  Since `x` could be 0 or 1, we don't know if the expression is 1^1 or 0^1,  which means that we don't know what the result of the expression should be.  This means that `q` will remain x for the rest of the simulation.  There will be no way to change its value.

Using the `clr` signal fixes that problem.  Typically, at the start of simulation (time=0), you would set clr=0 so that `q` is assigned a known value (0).  That prevents the x.

Even if you didn't start with clr=0, as soon as you do set clr=0 at a later time, that will resolve the x.

All of this applies to the `qn` signal as well.

---

Note: The 1st code example in the question has syntax errors.  I assume the `q` and `qn` assignments should have been inside `begin/end` blocks.